# How do I restrict access to System Pages?

Tags: 2013, security

I want a user group to only be able to access our published front-end site. How can I prevent these users from accessing System pages?

For example, I don't want them to be able to access /_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx

Comment: How about allowing inplview.aspx which is a rest call to sharepoint lists. We have some custom js code on publishing pages to display lists on a page. But we still want to deny system pages for forms based users who are read only.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a custom permission level based on Read, but deselect View Application Pages, that should prevent them from getting to those pages. Then apply this permission level to any desired group(s).

Comment: Is this done from central admin?

Comment: It could be done in central admin and applied to a web application f necessary, in this situation I think doing it at a site collection level would be fine.